# resolve updatable view to xml column?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have the following portion of a view definition

```
SELECT
   codedValue.value('Code[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS "Code",
   codedValue.value('Name[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS "Value"
  FROM GDB_ITEMS AS items 
  CROSS APPLY items.Definition.nodes
   ('/GPCodedValueDomain2/CodedValues/CodedValue') AS CodedValues(codedValue)
  WHERE items.Name = 'tlu_Loss_list'
```

which queries an application-generated xlm column for "code" and "value". In this context, I am able to read-only the codes and values in the xml column.

Ideally, I'd like to make the view updatable, so users can enter their own codes and values, which will be replicated over to this xml column. Is this possible?

Here is the relavent portion of the the xml column and table:

Existing data in xml column:

```
<GPCodedValueDomain2 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:typens="http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/10.0" xsi:type="typens:GPCodedValueDomain2">
  <DomainName>tlu_Loss_List</DomainName>
  <FieldType>esriFieldTypeString</FieldType>
  <MergePolicy>esriMPTDefaultValue</MergePolicy>
  <SplitPolicy>esriSPTDefaultValue</SplitPolicy>
  <Description>Loss_Reason</Description>
  <Owner>DBO</Owner>
  <CodedValues xsi:type="typens:ArrayOfCodedValue">
    <CodedValue xsi:type="typens:CodedValue">
      <Name>Abandoned</Name>
      <Code xsi:type="xs:string">AB</Code>
    </CodedValue>
    <CodedValue xsi:type="typens:CodedValue">
      <Name>Coyote</Name>
      <Code xsi:type="xs:string">CO</Code>
    </CodedValue>
  </CodedValues>
</GPCodedValueDomain2>
```

Table holding the XML:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GDB_ITEMS](
    [ObjectID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Type] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](226) NULL,
    [PhysicalName] [nvarchar](226) NULL,
    [Path] [nvarchar](512) NULL,
    [Url] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Properties] [int] NULL,
    [Defaults] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [DatasetSubtype1] [int] NULL,
    [DatasetSubtype2] [int] NULL,
    [DatasetInfo1] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [DatasetInfo2] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Definition] [xml] NULL,
    [Documentation] [xml] NULL,
    [ItemInfo] [xml] NULL,
    [Shape] [geometry])
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this with an "instead-of" trigger:  [Designing INSTEAD OF triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175158%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

For examples of modifying XML, see [modify() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187093.aspx) and [XML Data Modification Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177454)

Comment: Thanks Ann. Triggers aren't my challenge right now, I'm not clear on the xml insert syntax to place within the trigger.

Comment: I haven't done it myself, but the links I just added include explanations and examples.  Good luck!